# List view with Simple Adapter not showing text

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I have asked similar question today where the problem was with Array adapter.
I have tried now to set up List view with Simple adapter because i need header row and subrow with content.

Program starts without errors but screen is blank.

EDIT: Ive updated code, it now runs without problem. I think that problem was in Jsoup query for contentNode.

Here is the code:

```
    package com.example.studentservis;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import android.R.string;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {



        List<String> headersList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView listview;
        StableArrayAdapter adapter1;
        String from[] = {"naslov","sadrzaj"};
        int [] to =  { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            new SampleAsyncTask().execute();


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }




        public class SampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    webRequest();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

                for(int i = 0; i < headersList.size(); i++)
                {
                    Map<String,String>oglas = new HashMap<String,String>(2);
                    oglas.put("naslov", headersList.get(i));
                    oglas.put("sadrzaj", contentList.get(i));
                    data.add(oglas);
                }
                simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);

                listview.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
            }

        }



        private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

            HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                    List<String> objects) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                    mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                String item = getItem(position);
                return mIdMap.get(item);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return true;
            }
        }



        public void webRequest() throws Exception{
            String servisURL = "http://www.sczg.unizg.hr/student-servis/";

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(servisURL).get();

            Elements jobNode = doc.select("div.jobBox");
            Elements headersNode = jobNode.select("h1");
            Elements contentNode = jobNode.select("div.content");


            for(int i = 0; i < headersNode.size(); i++){
                headersList.add(headersNode.get(i).text());
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < contentNode.size(); i++){
                contentList.add(contentNode.get(i).text());
            }



        }

    }
```

Comment: call  setUpSimpleAdapter(); in onPostExecute() where it will execute in UI thread.

Comment: @Santhosh i think that im doing that with `listview.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);` in `onPostExecute` 
Or maybe not? :D

Comment: But, the method setUpSimpleAdapter() is in doInBackground(). So, my guess is that might be the problem. You are filling up the adapter in background AsyncTask thread and setting the adapter for listView in UI thread. so for that reason it might not be showing u any data in the list. Try once. its just a hunch.

Comment: System.out.println(response); are you sure this is not empty?

Comment: Nothing comes to console. I forgot to remove that. Connection works, i tested it before. When i try to set up simple adapter in `onPostExecute` i get error `The constructor SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.SampleAsyncTask, List<Map<String,String>>, int, String[], int[]) is undefined`

Comment: Correct this: SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, List<Map<String,String>>, int, String[], int[])

Comment: @imot01 my guess contentList is not populated with any data

Comment: @imot01 its better to display progress dialog till the data is loaded to the ui.

Comment: can you check using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Comment: @Raghunandan im going to check `contentNode` when i get emulator working. stupid shit doesnt want to start.

Comment: @imot01 sure let me know if you need further help.

Comment: @Raghunandan Ive checked `Elements contentNode = jobNode.select("div.content");` it works fine, i get content text. i dont know why it doesnt show when i try to do it with SimpleAdapter

Comment: @imot01 i tried logging in contentList. it does not print anything. I will check again

Comment: @imot01 the size is 0   System.out.println("............."+contentNode.size()); . logs 0. you had this Elements contentNode = jobNode.select("content");

Comment: @imot01 yup now it works. i will update my post. its because of this Elements contentNode = jobNode.select("content"); which went wrong

Comment: @Raghunandan I FINALLY DID IT ! hahah man im so happy. thanks for you help! i will update my post with answer

Comment: @imot01 i updated my post check the post if it helps accept the same. as i guess your contentList before was null coz you had this  Elements contentNode = jobNode.select("content");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way. I have modified the above. You can use the below for reference. Check the snap shot if the data in the listview is right.( coz i don't understand the text data). If the data in the list is not right modify the below accoridng to your requirements.

```
public class test extends Activity  {

String s;
List<String> headersList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView listview;

//    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
//    List<Map<String, String>> data2 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new SampleAsyncTask().execute();


}

public class SampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            webRequest();
            //setUpSimpleAdapter();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       // List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        Map<String,String>oglas = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < headersList.size(); i++)
        { 
            data.add(headersList.get(i));    
        }
         //my guess contentList is null. 
         //  can't understand the contents.
         // in that cases you can use headerList directly instead of adding to data
         // used array adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String> (test.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
        // instead of data you can use headerList.   
        listview.setAdapter(adapter1);
       // listview.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }

}


public void webRequest() throws Exception{
    String servisURL = "http://www.sczg.unizg.hr/student-servis/";
    String response = Jsoup.connect(servisURL).response().toString();
    System.out.println(response);
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(servisURL).get();

    Elements jobNode = doc.select("div.jobBox");
    Elements headersNode = jobNode.select("h1");
    Elements contentNode = jobNode.select("content");


    for(int i = 0; i < headersNode.size(); i++){
        headersList.add(headersNode.get(i).text());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < contentNode.size(); i++){
        contentList.add(contentNode.get(i).text());
    }
}
}
```

Edit:

The problem is this

```
      Elements contentNode = jobNode.select("content");
```

which should be

```
      Elements contentNode = jobNode.select("div.content");
```

Your contentList was null because of this ( as i guessed).

public class test extends Activity  {

```
String s;
List<String> headersList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView listview;
List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new SampleAsyncTask().execute();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}




public class SampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            webRequest();
            //setUpSimpleAdapter();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < headersList.size(); i++)
        {
            Map<String,String>oglas = new HashMap<String,String>(2);
            oglas.put("naslov", headersList.get(i));
            oglas.put("sadrzaj", contentList.get(i));
            data.add(oglas);
        }
        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(test.this, data, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                new String[]{"naslov","sadrzaj"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
        listview.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }

}


public void webRequest() throws Exception{
    String servisURL = "http://www.sczg.unizg.hr/student-servis/";
    String response = Jsoup.connect(servisURL).response().toString();
    System.out.println(response);
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(servisURL).get();

    Elements jobNode = doc.select("div.jobBox");
    Elements headersNode = jobNode.select("h1");
    //Elements contentNode = jobNode.select("content"); 
    Elements contentNode = jobNode.select("div.content"); 

    for(int i = 0; i < headersNode.size(); i++){
        headersList.add(headersNode.get(i).text());
    }
    System.out.println("............."+contentNode.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < contentNode.size(); i++){
        contentList.add(contentNode.get(i).text());

    }
}
}
```

[image]